# FFT: When i read an audio signal through an ADC .. is it the real or the imaginary part of signal

Tags: c, fft, microcontroller, adc

So am reading on the implementation of FFT from [The engineer's guide to DSP](http://www.dspguide.com/ch12/3.htm) its a pretty good book but there is something that is Confusing me ..

the signal being used in the examples consists of 2 parts .. real and imaginary ones .. when i read an audio signal from an ADC connected to a micro controller .. what is this signal .. is it the real part or the imaginary part ?? do i need to do some analysis first on the signal to extract the real/imaginary parts ??

am not very good at math so if u know the answer please simplify it as much as u can

much appreciated ^_^

Comment: The imaginary part of the Complex object isn't used when dealing with audio signals and FFT. But, most FFT implementations use Complex objects when calculation FFTs, so you have to initialize the imaginary part with zero.

Comment: oh so when i take a reading from the adc i put it in an object as the real part and initialize the imaginary part as zero ?

Comment: yes -- that's about it.

Comment: that was easier than i thought it would be haha ... thx alot things are getting clearer now ^_^

Comment: Regarding the DSP manual you reference, I think it is a really good resource for information, but it is quite dated. Some of the articles predict what will happen at the turn of the century! i.e. it is older than 20 years some of it. Much of the perspective and discussions regarding use of specific technologies, devices and languages are almost irrelevant/incorrect. e.g. DSPs vs CPUs; Fixed vs floating point; Assembly vs C; and 16-bit DSPs! Things have changed a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can just input the audio as a real signal, set the imaginary value inputs to zero. You only need to worry about both real and imaginary input values - also called a complex signal - when you have a complex input. One example of this would be in RF radios where you have an IQ signal resulting from IQ demodulation.

Bonus facts:

The resultant FFT output will then have Hermitian symmetry as a result of a real-only input signal. This basically means negative frequency points of the FFT will mirror positive frequency points, albeit with a sign inversion on the imaginary frequency components.

The above means that you will only be making use of half the available frequency bandwidth. A complex signal can carry twice as much frequency information as a real-only signal. But don't worry about this, you are dealing with audio not RF.

If you have stereo audio and you are using FFTs as an efficient implementation of FIR filters (multiplication in frequency domain is convolution in the time-domain), you could input the second audio input as imaginary to filter 2 channels of audio in one go. Note this does not apply when using FFTs for frequency analysis, as you must keep the signals separate. - again don't worry about this you're unlikely to need to worry about this.